# No POST, no video, beeps without RAM. What is more likely to be bad: CPU or MOBO?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

I bought a broken PC (HP p6320nl) from a classifieds site. When pressing the power button, fans spin, USB devices get powered and ethernet port blinks when a cable is attached. The CPU also gets hot. However, there's no video output, fan speed doesn't change even after a couple of minutes and computer doesn't get an IP address. There are also no beeps, unless I remove the RAM in which case it does emit a beep.

Now, from what I've read this usually points to one of 3 things:

- broken PSU
- broken MOBO
- broken CPU

I tested the PSU and external GPU on other computer, as well as the VGA cable and monitor. So they are not the problem. It leaves the motherboard and CPU. My question is: which one should I replace first? Is it rational to assume that CPU is more likely to be bad since the board does perform RAM check and gives power to USB and ethernet? It's important to me because I don't have a lot of money right now so I'd rather get it right the first time.